# Mozilla Firefox programmatic screen capture

Tags: javascript, firefox, screen, mozilla, capture

I'm interested in writing javascript that will programmatically perform a screen capture of what is viewed in the browser, and save the file to the hard disk. I'd like to be able to type in a list of keywords, and use a search engine's api to programmatically view the page, and take a screen capture.

My first question is, does this sounds like something that would violate the terms of my browser, Firefox, or any or all search engine api's? All of my web development experience is Internet Explorer. I'm aware of the various free and open source applications available, but am not familiar with their licenses.

Is this something that could be done using javascript? I've noticed that there are screen capture add-ons available to install. Is it possible to execute an add-on programmaticaly through javascript?

Is their a Firefox / Mozilla equivalent to an ActiveX control?

Any information would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

What is impossible? What I'm trying to do in general, or doing so using Firefox?

I came across a couple forums where comments advertised ActiveX controls that would perform a screen capture. Is there an equivalent technology in browsers other than Internet Explorer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use flash/Active X to do it. Check out Kpoint.in, It records the entire desktop from within the browser(Works only for Windows though). I think they are using their own Firefox extension for the Audio.